# operator<< overloading to call a print function trouble

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

Okay I'm a little stuck on trying to overload the << operator for my template class. The requirement is that the << operator must call a void print function defined for this class.

Here is the important stuff from the template header:

```
template <class T>
class MyTemp {
public:
    MyTemp();           //constructor

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const MyTemp<T>& a);

    void print(std::ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const;
```

and here is my print function basically it's a vector and prints last element to first:

```
    template <class T>
void Stack<T>::print(std::ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const
{
    for ( int i = (fixstack.size()-1); i >= 0 ; --i)
    {
        os << fixstack[i] << ofc;
    }
}
```

and here is how I have the operator<< overloaded:

```
    template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& a)
{
    // So here I need to call the a.print() function
}
```

But I am receiving an "unresolved external symbol" error. So really I guess I have two issues. The first, is the way to fix the error above. Second, once that is fixed would I just call a.print(os) inside << overload? I know it needs to return an ostream though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: read this faq: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates.html#faq-35.16

Comment: You call the class template `MyTemp` in the first snippet, and `Stack` in the others. Do you do that in your real code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to leave `print` public (as it is in your example), so the operator doesn't need to be a friend.

```
template <class T>
class MyTemp {
public:
    void print(std::ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const;
};

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const MyTemp<T>& a) {
    a.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

If you do need it to be private, then you need to declare the correct template specialisation to be a friend - your `friend` declaration declares a non-template operator in the surrounding namespace, not a template. Unfortunately, to make a template a friend you need to declare it beforehand:

```
// Declare the templates first
template <class T> class MyTemp;
template <class T> std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const MyTemp<T>&);

template <class T>
class MyTemp {
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& os, const MyTemp<T>& a);
    // With a template thingy here  ^^

private:
    void print(std::ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const;
};

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const MyTemp<T>& a) {
    a.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

Or you could define the operator inline:

```
template <class T>
class MyTemp {
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyTemp<T>& a) {
        a.print(os);
        return os;
    }

private:
    void print(std::ostream& os, char ofc = ' ') const;
};
```

For your last question:

> Second, once that is fixed would I just call `a.print(os)` inside `<<` overload? I know it needs to return an `ostream` though.

It does indeed need to return an `ostream` - so just return the one that was passed in, as in my example code.

Comment: Ah works perfectly thank you! Need to work on my template skills. I will keep this information in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This error means there is an symbol which could not be recognized by the linker.on what variable are u getting this error
and also please check on stack as well because there is a std::stack class available.

Answer (score 0):

As your `print` member function is public, there's no need to declare `operator<<` as `friend`.

Beware that you are using class `Stack` is your *overload*, and `MyTemp` above ...

Comment: My bad that's not how I have it in my code, I tried to change all instances of Stack to MyTemp when I posted to avoid confusion, missed that one. Thanks though.